# How to solve for an equation where the variable is added with an exponent?

Tags: problem-solving

I've got a formula that calculates for the $x$ using $y$. This seems like it should be easy, but I find myself hitting a wall due to the $(99 * y)$. Without that it would obviously be quite trivial. What steps are needed to solve the equation for $y$?

$x = (99 * y) + y^4$

Comment: There is no (easy) way to solve for $y$

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html

Comment: Wolfram Alpha will give the four exact solutions for $y$ in terms of $x,$ but they're far too complicated to be useful.

Comment: Ah, yes I hadn't thought to check WA. The results it spits out are indeed quite complex. Funny how such a simple looking equation turns into something like that.

Comment: Degree-$4$-polynomials are still solveable by radicals in general, this is no longer true for degree $5$ and higher.